# How to refactor this complicated html generator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

```
['content', 'answers', 'comments'].each do |t|
  break if results.length >= MAX_RESULTS
  Question.search_tank('', :conditions => conditions.merge(t => "#{search_term}"), :page => 1, :per_page => 5).each do |q|
    next if matched_qs.include? q.id
    matched_qs << q.id

    r = {:title => q.content, :value => app_question_url(q.app, q.id)}
    if t == 'content'
      r[:label] = highlight_matched(search_regex, q.content)
      r[:label] << "<span class='search-type'>Question</span>"
    else
      r[:label] = q.content
    end

    if t == 'answers'
      r[:label] = "<span class='search-type snippet'>Answer</span>" + [r[:label], get_snippet(search_regex, q.answers)].compact.join('<br />')
    end

    if t == 'comments'
      r[:label] = "<span class='search-type snippet'>Comment</span>" + [r[:type], r[:label], get_snippet(search_regex, q.answers.map(&:comments).flatten)].compact.join('<br />')
    end

    results << r
    break if results.length >= MAX_RESULTS
  end
```

I would like to refactor that part which generates r[:label]

Comment: is there a `results = []` before the loop? are you missing an `end` at the end? is this a helper?

Comment: Yes there is ``results = []`` before the loop and yes i miss ``end`` No this is no helper but ``search#new`` action which render json ``results.to_json`` https://gist.github.com/6738554e438c741fba45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs some tweaking, but I hope it helps you identify the main issues to address in your code (IMHO):

```
objects = [:content, :answers, :comments].flat_map do |type|
  questions = Question.search_tank('', {
    :page => 1, 
    :per_page => 5,
    :conditions => conditions.merge(type => search_term), 
  })
  questions.map { |q| [q, type] }
end.uniq_by(&:first).take(MAX_RESULTS)

results = objects.map do |q, type| 
  label = case type
  when :content
    highlight_matched(search_regex, q.content) + 
      content_tag(:span, "Question", :class => "search-type")
  when :answers
    content_tag(:span, "Answer", :class => 'search-type snippet'>) + 
      [q.content, get_snippet(search_regex, q.answers)].compact.join(tag(:br))
  when :comments
    comments = get_snippet(search_regex, q.answers.flat_map(&:comments))]    
    content_tag(:span, "Comment", :class => 'search-type snippet'>) +
      [t, q.content, comments].compact.join(tag(:br))
  end
  {:title => q.content, :value => app_question_url(q.app, q.id), :label => label}
end
```

Notes:

- Avoid stateful variables whenever possible (that's it, don't update inplace), work with expressions.
- Use Rails helpers (content_tag, tag, ...).
- Use symbols for key-like values, not strings.
- `"#{something}`" -> `something.to_s`
- map + flatten = flat_map. Even though you should able to write `q.answer_commments` in Rails 3.1 will the correct model settings.
- Use `case`, not a chain of `if`/`elsif` if the condition is on the same value.

Comment: And since this is no helper I can use ``content_tag``

Comment: can or can't? it does not matter if it's not a helper, you can always use helpers just with an `include` of the desired module.

Comment: Hmm, Of course I can`t :), thx

Comment: ``"#{content_tag(:span, "Answer", :class: 'search-type snippet')}" +
              [q.content, get_snippet(search_regex, q.answers)].compact.join(tag(:br))`` I dont know why I have to use ``#{}`` here ``to_s`` not working and i see html tags <br/> http://i.imgur.com/81mst.png